# Why can't I add a webresource to form in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am working with an on-premise instance of Dynamics CRM 2015. I have added web resources by creating them through the "Customize the System" window as well as by uploading them.

When I go to a form or dashboard to add these, it never works. I click Web Resource, find the web resource, fill out the form and submit and it just goes back to the Form edit screen and nothing happens!

No error is being shown or anything and it is driving me nuts! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What browser do you use? Try to use IE because FF and Chrome have issues exactly with customization of forms.

Comment: Oh snap, I didn't even think about that. I will give this a shot tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: @AndriiButenko, that fixed it! If you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What browser do you use? Try to use IE because FF and Chrome have issues exactly with customization of forms.

Answer (score 0):

I agree on using Internet Explorer. Or use debug tools marking the update always from server box, as it is a cache problem.